# How to Pass Telerik Grid column value to its ClientTemplate Function in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I have the Following Code in my View

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<DatabaseModel.RMAItemModel>()

 .Name("RMAItemsGrid")

 .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(u => u.RmaID).RouteKey("RmaID"))

 .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("SelectRMAItemList", "Order"))

.Columns(columns =>

   {

     var ids = "";
     columns.Bound(o => o.RmaItemNo).Hidden(true);
     columns.Template(@<text>@{ids = item.RmaID.ToString();}</text>).Hidden(true);
     columns.Bound(o => o.RefundType).Title("Refund Type").ClientTemplate(Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("RefundType<#= RmaItemNo #>").BindTo(CommonService.GetListItems(31, ids.ToString(), 0, "Refund", false)).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" }).ToHtmlString()).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
    }
```

In **ClientTemplate** of **RefundType** Column I call **Telerik DropDownList**
In Dropdown List I call a Function **CommonService.GetListItems(31, **ids.ToString(***) or **<#=RefundType#>** , 0, "Refund", false)*

I want to assign **RefundType** column value to **ids** 
or I need to assign **RefundType** colunn value directly into

CommonService.GetListItems(31, **ids.ToString(**) or **<#=RefundType#>** , 0, "Refund", false)

I cann't pass column value to function

**CommonService.GetListItems(31, ids.ToString(), 0, "Refund", false)**

I want to pass Column value instead of **ids**

Comment: thanks @cheesemacfly can u help this question